# what is meaning (full form) of fxr in hostfxr.dll?

Tags: .net

As far as I know, "hostfxr.dll" is used to resolve dotnet runtime for a .net application.

But, what does hostfxr stands for, specifically fxr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*fxr* stands for framework resolver
**hostfxr.dll** is responsible for determining the correct version of the .NET Core runtime and framework libraries needed based on the application's configuration and the available runtime installations on the **host** system.